# Postgres Rank As Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT name, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY love_count DESC) AS position FROM items
```

And I'd now like to do a where clause on the rank() function:

```
SELECT name, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY love_count DESC) AS position FROM items WHERE position = 1
```

That is, I want to query the most loved item for each user. However, this results in:

`PGError: ERROR:  column "position" does not exist`

Also, I'm using Rails AREL to do this and would like to enable chaining. This is the Ruby code that creates the query:

```
Item.select("name, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY love_count DESC) AS position").where("position = 1")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to "wrap" it into a derived table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT name, 
           rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY love_count DESC) AS position 
    FROM items
) t
WHERE position = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

My first thought was, "Use a common table expression", like this untested one.

```
WITH badly_named_cte AS (
  SELECT name, 
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                      ORDER BY love_count DESC) AS position 
  FROM items
)
SELECT * FROM badly_named_cte WHERE position = 1;
```

The problem you're seeing has to do with the logical order of evaluation required by SQL standards. SQL has to act as if column aliases (arguments to the `AS` operator) don't exist until *after* the WHERE clause is evaluated.

Comment: +1 For performance. I'm not sure exactly why, but the CTE seems to be about 2x faster than the nested join in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Keyo: Did you compare execution plans?